# VariableDoesNotExist error when testing for existence

Tags: django, django-templates

In my `base.html`, I want to render certain menus when a user is on most pages, but there a few where they can't be, so I have something a bit like this:

```
{% if menu_context %}
   <ul class="menu">...</ul>
{% endif %}
```

This works great, I have a base class for most of my views that adds this variable. The problem is on the pages without it set, I get:

```
[2016-05-12 13:37:44,819 base] DEBUG: Exception while resolving variable 'menu_context' in template 'index.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 905, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [menu_context] in u'[...]'
```

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Alternatively, is there a way to prevent those particular log statements. My logging config is:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s %(module)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
        },
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['null'],  # Quiet by default!
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.template.base': {
            'handlers': ['null'],  # Quiet by default!
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

...but this does not seem to suppress them!

Comment: You can write a context manager that adds the `menu_context` variable to every request context automatically.

Comment: @Selcuk This seems a bit heavy-handed for what I'm trying to achieve, but I'll do it that way if there's nothing better.

Comment: If you change `django.template.base` to `django.template` in your `loggers` config, that will silence the errors. Assuming there isn't a reason you have applied it only to `django.template.base`?

Comment: If the code that uses `menu_context` is all inside an `{% if menu_context %}` tag, then I don't think you should get that error. Can you show the template that is causing the error? I think you've got a bug in your template, so I wouldn't try to suppress the log messages.

Comment: @Alasdair Inside the if block, the object is used e.g.: `{% if menu_context %}{% for item in menu_context %}{{ item }}{% endfor %}{% endif %}` - I'm guessing this is the issue

Comment: I'm surprised that's causing an error. I would expect `{% if menu_context %}` to evaluate to `False` and for no error. I've seen `VariableDoesNotExist ` before, but it was for things like `{{ item|filter:menu_context }}`.

Comment: Yup, I'm getting the same thing with other variables used in similar ways, e.g. on my registration page, `{% if invite %}` is causing the same message.

Comment: I've seen code like `{% if variable_name %}` suddenly trigger errors, when before it didn't. I have no die why. I think there is a bug there somewhere, but it's hard to reproduce.